# Adobe acrobat 8 command line switches to recognize ocr text

Tags: pdf, adobe, ocr, acrobat, scanning

I want to use command line, to execute licensed adobe acrobat 8 to recognize OCR text a already scanned pdf document and make it fully searchable pdf?

Do you know what is the command line switch, parameter?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a command-line switch. You could write a Javascript action to perform this tasks.